# Sending additional coockie variables with failure

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I bother with sending additional coockies to server. I'm receiving coockies from server uses to connecting with success but when i try to add more data in coockie, server do not receive it. I tried few ways to fix it but now im tired and devoid of ideas. Looking forward for your any helpful replies!

Here is the code:

```
$cookie = 'var1='.urlencode($config['log']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://locaIp.adress/'); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('var1' => $config['log'],); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); $echo = curl_exec($ch); </i>
```

Comment: It could be that HttpOnly has been enabled. It´s purpose is to block the possibility to write to the cookie with a script.

Comment: This is not the problem, becouse im pretty sure that httponly is disabled.Maybe its problem with curl and javascript. I can use without problem received login cookies from server but i can't add more variables to it.

Answer (score 0):

HttpOnly was my initial pick, but you said that you post one var, but no multiple (I'm guessing that's what you mean adding more data). If that's the issue it should be preparing the data before you send it.

```
$cookie = 'log1='.urlencode($config2['log1']).";".'log2='.urlencode($config2['log2']);

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie ); // it works like this
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "log1=cookie1;log2=cookie2");    // or like this
```

Comment: In my real $cookie i have log1=somedata; log2=otherdata; and more but i think its no the problem in urlencode, becoude when i set cookies diretcly in cutl_setopt function im it still wont start working. I think problem is by the server side, becouse curl have problems with js"Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01" 
Any ideas?